# Scala Protocol Buffer and Maven issues

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, scalapb

My requirment is use Protocol Buffer on the Scala Play! REST API project and I'm having a hard time adding it. I followed the instructions in the documentation but it keeps failing. This is how it looks like:
my build.sbt

```
scalaVersion := "2.13.10"

dependencyOverrides += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-java8-compat" % "1.0.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  guice,
  "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "5.0.0" % Test,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "8.0.26",
  "io.getquill" %% "quill-jasync-mysql" % "4.6.0",
  "com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "scalapb-runtime" % "0.11.11"
)
```

and `project/scalapb.sbt`

```
addSbtPlugin("com.thesamet" % "sbt-protoc" % "1.0.3")
```

And trying to compile the project I get this output:

```
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run last protocExecutable for the full output
[error] (protocExecutable) lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.error.FetchError$DownloadingArtifacts: Error fetching artifacts:
[error] https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protoc/3.15.6/protoc-3.15.6-osx-aarch_64.exe: not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protoc/3.15.6/protoc-3.15.6-osx-aarch_64.exe
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed 4 Apr 2023, 14:26:17
```

Please advice on how to solve this. Thank you

I've tried to clean, update and reload. I've restarted the whole project and it doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a hint, not an answer: the generated URL is wrong. The correct is: `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protoc/3.15.6/protoc-3.15.6-osx-x86_64.exe`. Probably it is a missconfiguration or a bug in the plugin.

Comment: can you advise on how it's wrong? I'm following the documentation from here: https://scalapb.github.io/docs/installation

Answer (score 4):

Based on the URL in the error message, I assume you are using Apple Silicon M1 or M2 platform **aarch 64** architecture.

But that architecture haven't been supported in official `protoc` version 3.15.6.

The first supported version is: **3.17.3** which released in July 2021.

**Option 1.**

Upgrage `sbt-protoc` to 1.0.6 or above.

```scala
addSbtPlugin("com.thesamet" % "sbt-protoc" % "1.0.6")
```

**Option 2.**

Install Rosetta to be able run `x86_64` binaries on `aarch64` architecture.